# There are no repos

Tags: package-management, software-sources, source-packages

I have PC Engines Apu . I wanted to install Linux to Apu over PXE. I m trying to install this on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I am Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
#yum install tftp-server syslinux httpd dhcpd

There are no enabled repos.
 Run "Yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>

#yum repolist all
repolist: 0
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what Operating System you are running? `yum` is a RedHat & co. command, and while it is possible to install on Ubuntu, there's not much reason to. Please [edit] your question and clarify whether you're using Ubuntu or not.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 LST.

Comment: there's no `tftp-server` package in Ubuntu 14.04 repos. Though there's a package `tftp`.

Comment: Can I install tftp-server package on Ubuntu 14.04  ?

Comment: Tftp is the user interface to the Internet TFTP (Trivial File Transfer
Protocol), which allows users to transfer files to and from a remote machine.
The remote host may be specified on the command line, in which case tftp uses
host as the default host for future transfers.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? then it's `tftp`. You can list all available `tftp` packages with command: `apt-cache policy tftp*`

Comment: I want to Install CentOS 6.5 64bit over PXE to  PC Engines APU. http://wiki.polaire.nl/doku.php?id=install_centos_6.5_on_pc_engine_s_apu_over_pxe

Comment: You want to install _CentOS_? 1) the commands you are using are completely irrelevant then and 2) your question is completely off topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing CentOS (according to the OP's comment).

Answer (score 7):

The `yum` package manager comes from RedHat and its derivatives. It installs rpm packages from repositories that store such packages. The Debian (and by extension, Ubuntu) repositories have .deb packages instead. The equivalent of `yum` in the Debian/Ubuntu world is `apt-get`. I have no idea why you ended up with `yum` installed on your Ubuntu system but it's not the tool you want to use.

What you're after is:

```
sudo apt-get install tftp tftpd syslinux apache2 dhcpcd
```

In any case, that's my best guess since you don't actually explain what you're trying to install. There's no `tftp-server` package in Ubuntu so I'm guessing you want `tftpd` which is a server that supports the TFTP protocol. Likewise, there's no `httpd` in Ubuntu but I'm guessing you want to install the `apache2` webserver and a `dhcp` client (`dhcpd`).